# How to fetch value of selected option in dropdown?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, asp.net-ajax

I have a dropdown in my View. The dropdown shows enumerated values:

```
      @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.hobbyhome.HobbyDetailList.First().course, HobbyHomesWebApp.Utility.EnumList.ToSelectList(HobbyHomes.Model.Course.Advance, "Select Course"), "--Select Course--", new { @id="Course"}) <font color="red">*</font>
```

**Generator For Course**

```
  <div class="editor-field">
 <select id="course" name="course"><option value="">--Select Course--              </option>
     <option value="Basic">Basic Level</option>
      <option value="Intermidiate">Intermidiate Level</option>
       <option value="Advance">Advance Level</option>
      </select> <font color="red">*</font>   
              </div>

   var course = from Course c in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Course))
                         select new { ID = c, Name = c.ToString() };
                        ViewData["course"] = new SelectList(course, "ID", "Name");
```

**Involved Input** options are Basic, intermediate and Advance

I am trying to populate other dropdowns based on the selected value:

```
    $("#Course").change(function () {
        var Hobbyid = $("#Hobby").val();
        var Cid=$("#Course").val();
        var urlHobbyhome = '@Url.Action("FetchStateByHobbyId")';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: urlHobbyhome,
            data: { id: Hobbyid,cid:Cid },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#State').empty();
                $('#State')
                        .append($('<option>', { value: "0" })
                        .text("-- Select State --"));
                $.each(data, function (key, value) {

                    $('#State')
                        .append($('<option>', { value: value.Value })
                        .text(value.Text));
                });
            }
        });
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please add the html generated with the involved inputs...

Comment: @Romias 
I have edited my Question

Comment: I don't see any new HTML... your problem is still the same or now you can get the Course ID and find some other problem?

Comment: @Romias I'm still not able to get the CourseId :(...

Comment: please... post the HTML you see on your browser. So far you posted javascript, the Razor View and the controller... we need to see the generated HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to attach to Change event of your DropDownList.

```
$("#YourDropDownID").change(function () {
     var itemSel = $("#YourDropDownID").val();
     // Do your Ajax logic using the selected value stored in variable 'itemSel'

});
```

**EDIT:**

Test this function:

```
$("#course").change(function () {
        var Hobbyid = $("#Hobby").val();
        var Cid=$("#course").val();
        alert("This is the CourseID:" + Cid);  
        var urlHobbyhome = '@Url.Action("FetchStateByHobbyId")';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: urlHobbyhome,
            data: '{id:' + Hobbyid + 'cid:' + Cid + '}',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#State').empty();
                $('#State')
                        .append($('<option>', { value: "0" })
                        .text("-- Select State --"));
                $.each(data, function (key, value) {

                    $('#State')
                        .append($('<option>', { value: value.Value })
                        .text(value.Text));
                });
            }
        });
});
```

I changed the "data" property to a concatenation of strings because there is some problem when using the "id" name. Added an Alert showing the selected Course Id, and changed the selectors to use lowercase ids. Please completely replace your javascript function with mine and let us now.

Comment: I did the same thing bt i'm not able to get the selected drop down's value.....mayb because its an enum

Comment: Just check via Firebug or looking at the generated HTML, what is the real ID of your DDL. Could be something like: 'hobbyhome.HobbyDetailList.Course'

Comment: Well toavoid this i exclusively gave it an ID as "new {@id="course"}"

But it still doesnt giv me any value due to wich my ajax is not being called

I'll udate my Question and tell u wat i did

Comment: @priya77, please post the generated HTML for that DropDownList-